# Why don't we say Avinu Malcanu on Tisha B' Av?

Tags: halacha, tisha-bav, tachanun

Why don't we say Avinu Malcanu on Tisha B' Av?

The Artscroll Siddur says "on fast days that tachanun is omitted...", is there any other reason?

Comment: I once heard a nice vort: The month of Elul is the month of Avinu-Malkeinu. The month of Av is just plain Avinu (a much closer relationship) ...

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason that I recall is because of the pasuk in Eichah (1:15) that refers to the day as "moed"

קָרָא עָלַי מוֹעֵד לִשְׁבֹּר בַּחוּרָי

I don't remember why that forces a connection.

Comment: "I don't remember why that forces a connection" - The term מוֹעֵד  is synonymous with "Yom Tov" in this context. SInce we omit *Tachanun* on *Yom Tov* we omit it on *Tish'a B'Av*. I think Art Scroll Eicha may explain why Tish'a B'Av was called a "Mo'ed" or what was meant in that verse.

Answer (score 3):

My rav explained that Tachanun (which, is part of your question, per se, not necessarily the direct reason why Avinu Malkeinu) is omitted on occasions of either "extreme" - extreme joy or extreme sadness.

Yom Tov is "extreme joy" so Tachanun is omitted.

In a house of mourning during the week of shiva, Tachanun is also omitted. This is a location & time of extreme sadness.

If Tachanun is omitted in a house of mourning where one person is mourning, kal vachomer it should be omitted when all of B'nei Yisra'el is mourning!

Answer (score 0):

Edited to change my answer. [Here is a link that explains why we don't say Avinu Malkeinu on Tisha B'Av.](http://www.ou.org/chagim/roshchodesh/av/5761.htm)

Comment: It would be useful if you summarized the linked webpage, even in just one or two sentences.

Comment: Link takes you to the root. If anyone can add in the text, I would appreciate it.